# Next large integer answer after a division in java android

Tags: java, android

How do i get next large integer after division in java android

for example

11/5 = 2.2, wanted to round of this answer 3 not to 2

My calculations are complex and final answer, I need to show rounded of to next big integer value

Regards

Sujay

Comment: add 0.5 to your answer you will get next high integer

Comment: duplicate question 
Math.ceil() is the correct function to call

Comment: In Java, integer division returns the integer value of the division it does not return float.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `ceil` method,

```
double ans = ((double) 11) / 5;
double result = Math.ceil(ans);
```